# How to serialize a vector into an array of chars

Tags: c++, serialization, vector, winsock

I have a vector defined as:

```
std::vector<message *>
```

where message is:

```
struct message{
    static unsigned int last_id;
    unsigned int id;
    std::string msg;
    std::string timestamp;
}
```

My objective is to send this information using Winsock (from server to client), but this only allows sending chars as it appears in WinSock2.h. Taking this into account, I want to serialize all the information (id, msg and timestamp) in an array of chars in order to send it all together, and in the client, have a function to deserialize so as to have the same vector I had in the server.

How could I implement it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please review [MCVE].  Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: I've been searching for many ways to implement it, but I couldn't find any valid solution. Any key fact to start serializing would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Winsock, but probably similar to what I have used. Imagine all 4 of your items 'compacted' into a single vector of chars (I use std::string).  How would the destination find the individual fields? Perhaps a protocol of your own invention?   A (somewhat) related area is called 'persistent storage', I believe some packages exist, don't remember the name, though.  Good luck.

Comment: To send from client to server I use a protocol of my own (data divided in ";", that is to say, i send "cmd;username;msg;". The problem comes when sending from server to client, that I need to send more information (various user messages, followers etc.) , that it is quite tedious to send all that information separated by ";". Thanks anyway for the answer!

Comment: Why are you storing the time stamp as a string?

Comment: "i send "cmd;username;msg;"." -- ok, but msg appears to be a std::string.  You can not be sent it directly ... you must extract the data portion (which is not contiguous in the 'msg', in most implimentations). and resides instead elsewhere (probably what we call the stack).  The same with most of the stl.  I suspect Winsock routines might not know how to extract data.  Linux tcp/ip does not.

Comment: So... "how do I serialise"? You didn't bother Googling? Reading a book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following offers a simple approach for the serialization problem.

However, note that **it is not portable**. It assumes same environment conditions on both sides (client/server), i.e. endianness and sizeof int and size_t. This assumption is probably unsatisfactory when writing server/client programs, and your code should handle this aspect as well.

For example, if you can say that 32 bits is a sufficient size for the `id` value and the length of your strings, you can use [htonl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when serializing, and [ntohl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when deserializing.

**Serializer:**

```
class MessageSerializer
{
public:
    MessageSerializer(const message& messageStruct)
    : m_msgRef(messageStruct)
    , m_msgLength(m_msgRef.msg.length())
    , m_timeLength(m_msgRef.timestamp.length())
    {}

    size_t RequiredBufferSize() const
    {
        return sizeof(int) + sizeof(size_t)*2 + m_msgLength + m_timeLength;
    }

    void Serialize(void* buffer) const
    {
        PushNum     (buffer, m_msgRef.id);
        PushString  (buffer, m_msgRef.msg.c_str(), m_msgLength);
        PushString  (buffer, m_msgRef.timestamp.c_str(), m_timeLength);
    }
private:
    const message&  m_msgRef;
    const size_t    m_msgLength;
    const size_t    m_timeLength;

    template<typename INTEGER>
    void PushNum(void*& buffer, INTEGER num) const
    {
        INTEGER* ptr = static_cast<INTEGER*>(buffer);
        //copying content
        *ptr = num;
        //updating the buffer pointer to point the next position to copy
        buffer = ++ptr;
    }
    void PushString(void*& buffer, const char* cstr, size_t length) const
    {
        PushNum(buffer, length);
        //copying string content
        memcpy(buffer, cstr, length);
        //updating the buffer pointer to point the next position to copy
        char* ptr = static_cast<char*>(buffer);
        ptr += length;
        buffer = ptr;
    }
};
```

**Deserializer:**

```
class MessageDeserializer
{
public:
    MessageDeserializer(const char* messageBuffer)
    : m_msgBuffer(messageBuffer)
    {}

    void Deserialize(message& messageOut)
    {
        messageOut.id           = PopNum<int>(m_msgBuffer);
        messageOut.msg          = PopString(m_msgBuffer);
        messageOut.timestamp    = PopString(m_msgBuffer);
    }

private:

    const void* m_msgBuffer;

    template<typename INTEGER>
    INTEGER PopNum(const void*& buffer) const
    {
        const INTEGER* ptr = static_cast<const INTEGER*>(buffer);
        //copying content
        INTEGER retVal = *ptr;
        //updating the buffer pointer to point the next position to copy
        buffer = ++ptr;

        return retVal;
    }

    std::string PopString(const void*& buffer) const
    {
        size_t length = PopNum<size_t>(buffer);
        const char* ptr = static_cast<const char*>(buffer);
        //copying content
        std::string retVal(ptr, length);
        //updating the buffer pointer to point the next position to copy
        ptr += length;
        buffer = ptr;

        return retVal;
    }
};
```

Then your using code could be something like:

```
//...
MessageSerializer serializer(*myVector[i]);
char* buffer = new char[serializer.RequiredBufferSize()];
serializer.Serialize(buffer);
```

and:

```
//...
message myMsg;
MessageDeserializer(input).Deserialize(myMsg);
```

Comment: Thank you @R.G. The code seems to work, but I get an error before compiling when creating the serializer. It says in `*myVector[i]` (already substituted by my `vector<message *>`) that _no operator matches these operands "*". Operand types are: * std::vector<message *, std::allocator<message *>>_. I've tried creating new vectors in order to see if the problem was with mine, but the problem persists. I'd appreciate much any help!

Comment: Try to write the expression with parenthesis, like this: `*(myVector[i])` (the [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) ensures that the expression means the same, but it may bring out the cause for the syntax error).

If it still persists, type here the full statements of the variable definition (myVecor) and when it's used as in the above expression.

Comment: Problem fixed! I was accessing to the whole vector of messages instead of a single one. Thanks for your time @R.G.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Boost serialization library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/serialization/doc/) to save/load your structure to an array of char. The boost library is widely used in C++, and if you're not familiar with it, I'd recommend taking a look at it.

Instead of using winsock, you could learn to use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) sockets and make your C++ code work on almost any platform, instead of just Windows, but that's another topic.

Here's an example of how to serialize your vector, and recover it from the other side of the socket:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>

struct message {
    static unsigned int last_id;
    unsigned int id;
    std::string msg;
    std::string timestamp;

    template <class ArchiveT>
    void serialize(ArchiveT& ar, const unsigned int /*version*/) // function used to serialize (save/load) data from the boost serialization library
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("LastId", last_id);
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Id", id);
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Msg", msg);
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Timestamp", timestamp);
    }
};

unsigned int message::last_id;

template <class T>
void serialize_save(const T& obj, std::string& outString)
{
    std::stringstream binaryOut;
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive outArchive(binaryOut);
    outArchive << obj;

    outString = binaryOut.str();
}

template <class T>
void serialize_load(T& dataOut, const void* data, const size_t dataSize)
{
    const char* dataPtr = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data);
    std::string dataString(dataPtr, dataPtr + dataSize);
    std::stringstream dataStream(dataString);
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive binArchive(dataStream);
    binArchive >> dataOut;
}


void init_vector(std::vector<message*>& vect) {
    const size_t vectorSize = 2;

    vect.resize(vectorSize);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vectorSize; i++) {
        vect[i] = new message();
        vect[i]->last_id = 0;
        vect[i]->id = 1;
        vect[i]->msg = "This is a message";
        vect[i]->timestamp = "12:02pm";
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<message*> messages;
    init_vector(messages); // initialize the vector. set it to any data

    std::string outputBuffer;
    serialize_save(messages, outputBuffer); // save the vector to a string (array of char)

    socket_write(outputBuffer.c_str(), outputBuffer.size()); // write the serialized data to the socket

    // on the reception side
    std::string receiveBuffer;
    socket_read(receiveBuffer); // receive socket data

    std::vector<message*> receivedMessages;
    serialize_load(receivedMessages, receiveBuffer.c_str(), receiveBuffer.size()); // from the array of character recover the vector
    // here the vector receivedMessages contains the same values saved in init_vector()
}
```

You can change the export format if you'd like by changing the `boost::archive::binary_iarchive` object. For instance, replace it to `boost::archive::xml_iarchive` for serializing objects to XML. There are other formats provided by the library. Another advantage is that it supports versioning.

Comment: Thank you @J-Mik . I appreciate your answer, but I need to do it in Winsock. Anyway I'll take a look to Boost serialization library in case it helps me in other aspects.